# Hide Font Awesome Icons if Cannot Load Font

Tags: css, iframe, fonts, font-awesome

Is there a way to hide [font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) icons if they can't load the font for whatever reason?

When my site is loaded in an `<iframe>` all the icons are displayed as squares.

Presumably there is some kind of cross-site security reason for this - but can I make a script to hide the icons instead of displaying the ugly squares that it shows in place of the icons?

Comment: In theory, I think you could do an AJAX request in JavaScript to the font file and check if the response was successful. If it fails, then you can add a class to your `body` element along with some styles, such as `body.no-font-awesome .fa { display: none; }`. I think this would be susceptible to a "flash of un-styled content", though.

Comment: Hmmmm, do you think I will not have this problem if I load my font from a CDN?

Comment: If you're not already using the CDN provided by FontAwesome on their website, it is worth a try. If you're hosting it locally now, the server might not be configured properly for all the different font types (servers don't typically set the appropriate MIME types for WOFF fonts by default), which may or may not be the issue. Their CDN should be serving everything properly, though.

Comment: Ok, I solved it....sorta.....I loaded the CSS from the CDN.....and then, on the line underneath, loaded my native CSS to overwrite it.....so if it fails to load my CSS properly then it has some backup from the CDN to use instead.....solved the problem until I find a more optimum solution...

Comment: If you can create a minimum example showing your implementation, it will help with understanding what the core problem is.

Comment: Why would your full site ever be loaded in an iframe? Other than for click-jacking purposes, in which case: "wat."

Answer (score 2):

[Edit : **final answer**]

So I did play on this case with the CSS Font API], and a solution could be as follow :

```css
    #content i {
      font-family: var(--myfont), sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link id="FA" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script>
      var fontFamily = false;

      let loadFont = async (family) => {
        console.log("Checking font presence.");
        await document.fonts.load(`1em '${family}'`)
          .then((oneFont) => {
            if (oneFont.length === 0) {
              console.log("Font not loaded :/");
            } else {
              console.log("Font loaded", oneFont);
              let html = document.querySelector("html");
              html.style.setProperty('--myfont', `${family}`)
            }
          });
      }

      loadFont("FontAwesome");

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        <i class="fas fa-camera-retro icon"></i>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <i class="far fa-thumbs-up icon"></i>
        Sed ac dapibus velit, eu consequat lectus.
        <i class="fas fa-heart icon"></i>
        Nunc at elit vel velit condimentum ultrices.
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle icon"></i>
        Nulla facilisi.
        <i class="fas fa-star icon"></i>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

This way we :

- wait for the font to be loaded
- if not ok, an information message is logged, but no action is required as we have a fallback font family in the css
- if and only if the font is loaded, we apply it to  tags.

So, in case of issue with the font, sans-serif family is applied.

[original answer]

I discovered and did play a little with [CSS Font Loading API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API), and I think it may cover your goals. Here we can test if FontAwesome stylesheet is loaded or not and then act in consequence. Of course, it stays theoretical and has to be tested in real conditions.

```js
let loadFont = async () => {
  console.log("Checking FontAwesome presence."); 
  await document.fonts.load("1em FontAwesome")
    .then((FA) => {
      if (FA.length === 0) {
        console.log("No FontAwesome here :/");       
      } else {
        console.log("FontAwesome ok", FA);
      }
    });
}

let removeFA = async () => {
  document.getElementById("FA").remove();
  loadFont();
}

(async() => { 
  await loadFont();
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link id="FA" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="removeFA();">FontAwesome ok? Now remove it.</button>
</body>

</html>
```